# How to avoid the deploy of sources from Jenkins (to Nexus) in deploy phase?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a Jenkins+Nexus installation, and some project there that are automated.

Jenkins deploy the sources and javadocs to nexus in the deploy phase (I am using Maven Release) -- Javadoc could be ok but  I don't want to have any sources in Nexus.

I was searching and googling and I don't know how to skip this step.

Thanks a lot

Output from jenkins

```
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ projectA ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyBuild/workspace/target/checkout/MyProject/projectA/target/projectA-1227.jar to .../projectA-1227.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyBuild/workspace/target/checkout/MyProject/projectA/pom.xml to .../projectA-1227.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyBuild/workspace/target/checkout/MyProject/projectA/target/projectA-1227-sources.jar to .../projectA-1227-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyBuild/workspace/target/checkout/MyProject/projectA/target/projectA-1227-javadoc.jar to .../projectA-1227-javadoc.jar
[INFO] [INFO]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding : `-Darguments="-Dsource.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"`

to your maven release plugin config (`Jenkins` > `your build configuration` > `Maven release build` > `Release goals and options`

Comment: It seems to work, if is all right in our next real deploy I will give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

By default this actually does not happen automatically. Most likely you have configured a release profile somewhere in your pom hierarchy that adds the Maven Source Plugin execution.

You could remove that if you never want to use it or otherwise change the release plugin config to use a different profile or skip source creation or invoke the build with parameters to skip as Guilame has answered

Comment: Yes I know,  but I was unable to find what dependency is generating the docs and the sources

Comment: It is not a dependency .. it must be one of the parent pom's up the inheritance tree. Just follow the coordinates..

Comment: it was a typo, i mean plugin, not dependency. I will check again the effective pom, anyway Guillame answer was perfect